# Hibernate + MySQL висит программа

Tags: mysql, hibernate, maven, intellij-idea

Изучил Java Core.
Теперь перешел к технологиям.

Есть задача: сделать CRUD с hibernate + spring mvc + mysql;

Начал разбираться сначала с hibernate.

Когда тестирую в мейне работоспособность, то запрос отправляется и в базу пользователь попадает, так же спокойно забирает этого пользователя назад и выводит его данные но программа так и не завершается.. и продолжает висеть как на скрине в чем проблема? Почему так?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

DAO

```
package table.dao.impl;

import Util.HibernateUtil;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import table.User;
import table.dao.UserDao;

import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by lol on 04.08.2015.
 */
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {
    public void addUser(User user) throws SQLException {
        Session session = null;
        try{
            session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            session.beginTransaction();
            session.save(user);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            if((session != null) && (session.isOpen())) session.close();
        }

    }

    public void deleteUser(User user) throws SQLException {
        Session session = null;
        try{
            session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            session.beginTransaction();
            session.delete(user);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            if(session != null && session.isOpen()) session.close();
        }
    }

    public User getUser(int id) throws SQLException {
        User result = null;

        Session session = null;
        try{
            session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            result = (User)session.get(User.class,id);

        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            if(session != null && session.isOpen()) session.close();
        }

        return result;
    }

    public List<User> getAllUser() throws SQLException {
        List<User> users = null;

        Session session = null;
        try{
            session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            users = session.createCriteria(User.class).list();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            if(session != null && session.isOpen()) session.close();
        }

        return users;
    }
}
```

Сессия

```
package Util;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

/**
 * Created by lol on 04.08.2015.
 */
public class HibernateUtil {
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory = null;

    private HibernateUtil(){}
    static {
        try {
            sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        }catch (Throwable e){
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(e);
        }

    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory(){
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

Модель таблицы

```
package table;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Date;


/**
 * Created by lol on 04.08.2015.
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {
    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    public int getId() {

        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }


    @Column(name = "age")
    private int age;

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }



    @Column(name = "isAdmin")
    private Boolean isAdmin;
    public void setIsAdmin(Boolean isAdmin) {
        this.isAdmin = isAdmin;
    }

    public Boolean getIsAdmin() {
        return isAdmin;
    }


    @Column(name = "createdDate")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date createdDate;
    public Date getCreatedDate() {
        return  createdDate;
    }

    public void setCreatedDate(Date createdDate) {
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", age=" + age +
                ", isAdmin=" + isAdmin +
                ", createdDate=" + createdDate +
                '}';
    }
}
```

User.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="table.User" table="user">
        <id name="id" column="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <generator class="increment"/>
        </id>
        <property name="name" column="name" type="java.lang.String"/>
        <property name="age" column="age" type="java.lang.Integer"/>
        <property name="isAdmin" column="isAdmin" type="java.lang.Boolean"/>
        <property name="createdDate" column="createdDate" type="java.sql.Date"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Answer (score 1):

Походу сэссия не закрывается. Этот тригер действительно срабатывает? Проверял?

```
if(session != null && session.isOpen()) session.close();
```

Если нет попробуй это. Не очень красиво, но должно сработать.

```
session.getSessionFactory().close();
session.close;
```